# Process Id of the client in Server Client App in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process, client-server, console-application

How can i get the process id of the client in a simple server client application in c#. I have a console application in C# which acts as a server and this can connect to multiple clients which are in the form of win-forms. When a client connects to the server, i want to display the process id of that process. So in the console it would print like Process 1342 connected. Again if i run the executable again and connect it should show the process id of this particular instance like Process 4532 connected and so on. Any suggestions

Regards

PS:
 I am able to pass the pid from the client side but i want to now if thereis some way by which i can get it in the server side only

Comment: I guess you'd need to provide a means for your clients to send the process id to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no immediate way to get this from the client's network connection alone. The client will have to derive its id and send it over when it connects as part of your connection protocol (perhaps along with other useful metadata such as build info, OS info etc.)

Comment: yes i am able to do it that way ...i just wanted to ask if i can to that in the server side only

Comment: No. Your connection will only give you your remote connection details

Comment: The server might not even be on the same machine as the client. The client could even be on an embedded system that doesn't even have process IDs. How would the server know unless the client tells it at some level of their protocol? (at TCP/IP level, only the MAC and IP addresses and the TCP port are sent, there is no process ID)